# Renaming a chart while using its location to select it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that will rename a chart. it needs to be able to locate the chart based of its top left cell, A1 for example. I've got the renaming portion of the code working but i cant seem to figure out how to work the the top left cell.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject.topleftcell

Comment: That selects the cell behind it, how do i select the chart itself from there

Comment: Please, test the code I supplied.

Comment: You implement it the way @FaneDuru illustrates in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub ChartChangeName()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, ch As ChartObject
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   For Each ch In sh.ChartObjects
        If ch.TopLeftCell.Address = "$A$1" Then
            ch.Name = "MyNewName": Exit For
        End If
   Next
End Sub
```